# Keras loss function promoting risky guess

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have troubles to fit my keras model on a complex time series, as it keeps converging toward a constant output (same prediction regardless of the input) corresponding to the average of the data.

I think that one way to get away with this issue would be a loss function that would give high reward for very good guesses, and low penalty for very bad ones. I want the cumulated loss to be lower with one good prediction and three totally wrong ones than with four average predictions.

Which pre-computed Keras loss function would you suggest for this?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I maybe should have specify that it is for the prediction of a time series, taking real values between -1 and 1. I think binary cross entropy is only suited for binary classification problems, isn't it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.